# how is shopify rendering the pages with their own made up tags

Tags: template-engine, shopify

i know they have something like smarty but i noticed another site called storenvy.com is using the same thing that shopify is. is there an api or something that i dont know about?

they have tags like

```
{{ shop.url }}
```

how are they making this if you know of any tutorial i can get into that would be great
thanks

Comment: yes i know of smarty but their not using smarty

Comment: @Sarmen B.: so what? they implemented some custom templating engine. If you're curious about implementation - just open their code and read it.

Comment: lol i wish, their not open source.

Comment: oops ;-) well, I bet it is built on the top of several complex regexes, like smarty is.

Comment: yea probably ill have to study every templating server side story to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Shopify uses [Liquid](https://github.com/shopify/liquid) to render those tags. It's an open source Ruby library [Tobi](http://twitter.com/tobi) wrote a while back that makes caching really easy on Shopify’s side.